# Trying to get 1 char input in 'C' Programming, program skips steps by amount of characters

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    scanf("%c", &input);
    choice = ChooseGame(input);
}

// ChooseGame function (Definition)
int ChooseGame(char input)
{
    switch (input) {
        case '1':   choice = 1;
        printf("Game 1!");
        break;
    default:
        choice = 0;
        printf("Wrong input, please try again!\n");
    }

    return choice;
}
```

I'm trying to get 1 char input but if for example the user inputs "234" it skips 3 steps instead of 1.

How can i fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this is `\n` left over by the previous `scanf` (on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
Try this

```
scanf(" %c",&input);
   //  ^space
```

A space before the format specifier `%c` eat up all the newline characters and will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&input); ` - That will not fix the problem - it will ignore the first input by user.

Comment: @Acme; No. A space before `%c` will eat up any number of newline chars.

Comment: Ah! yes i debugged it now.

Comment: @Acme; Better to improve your answer with `while(getchar() != '\n');`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the trailing newline due to the enter keystroke or some whitespace character do this:

```
for(i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    scanf("%c",&input);
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    choice = ChooseGame(input);
}
```

Sample [output](http://ideone.com/vIvYiC)

Or you can put a space before the `%c` in `scanf`:

```
for(i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    scanf(" %c",&input);
    choice = ChooseGame(input);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm sure it will work but since i'm doing a project which doesn't include the getchar() function haccks' solution works the best for me!

Comment: @user2996635 - `getchar` is in `stdio.h`